# Python using booleans to return a list for each item in the a list that is the same as another list

Tags: python, list, boolean

```
def find_fully_correct(answer, guess):
    """(list,list) -> list
    Return a list containing a 'b' for each correctly positioned color in the guess
    >>>find_fully_correct(['g','b','r','b'], ['g','b','r','b'])
    ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
    """
    if list(guess) is == list(answer) : 
        return list = ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
```

I'm trying to find a function that will evaluate the guess for each string in its list and compare it against the the string in the same position in the answer, if the strings are the same at the position for it to put a string 'b' at that same postion in a new list

Comment: And what should be returned if the two characters are *not* equal?

Comment: Is this really so difficult? Iterate through the `answer` and `guess` lists and compare all items, if the items are equal append a 'b' to your result. It really doesn't get much easier than this.

Comment: nothing should be returned so the list should be as long as the the number of correct positions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def find_fully_correct(answer, guess):
    res = []
    for x, y in zip(guess, answer):
        if x == y:
            res.append("b")
    return res if res else None
```

Comment: except i dont want python to return anything if the answer is different

Comment: see that still returns a none if the answer and guess are different in that position I want python to return nothing if the answer and guess are different only returning a 'b' if they are correct at one position  or 2 'b''s if they are correct at two positions

Comment: But you also said *"for it to put a string 'b' at that same postion in a new list"*.

Comment: Anyway, my last try. See if that is what you want.

Comment: sorry that was my mistake i realized it can't return 'b' in that position if they are different in other positions

Answer (score 1):

```
['b' for i in range(len(guess)) if answer[i]==guess[i]]
```

Comment: +0.5 for the very pythonic answer, and another +0.5 for not explaining how it works. If OP wants to learn something he'll have to show some effort.

Comment: but i would like python to return a list of 'b' in that position so

Comment: @Rawing `zip()` is the Pythonic way.

Comment: list('b' for i in range(len(guess))) if answer[i]==guess[i]

Comment: @Deka List comprehension create a list only. Have you tried running the code?